# Odd Laravel behavior for request input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function that receives the checked checkboxes from a form using:

```
$checked  = $request->input('selection');
```

I then store the changes to the database, however whenever the ID is over ~2040 it doesn't save, so I tried:

```
$checked  = $request->input('selection');
    dd($checked);
```

And checking it never returns the values over that, I just get:

```
array:4 [▼
 0 => "1060"
 1 => "1061"
 2 => "1062"
 3 => "1848"
 ]
```

Where nothing over that will return from `$checked  = $request->input('selection');`.  I've determined that the exact number it breaks at is 2054, if that holds any relevance.  These is the first line in the function so there is no other code affecting this that I can tell.

Comment: Can you show us your form code?

Comment: Not a [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) issue? Not clear how many inputs there are...

Comment: There are about 1100 inputs - the IDs start at 1060 (if that's what you mean).

Comment: @ceejayoz Trying to figure out how to edit my post to include the code

Comment: @ficuscr OOOOOH. Good call. Default's 1,000.

Comment: ahhhh... That would make sense then I think.. That can be edited, I assume?  php.ini?

Comment: @user2796515 See the duplicate thread I've linked. You need to raise the `max_input_vars` value in `php.ini`.

Comment: Why do I get a -1 for this question?  If anyone would take the time to explain I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user2796515 Not sure honestly. Yes it's a dupe but you can't know that when you ask. Try not to sweat it. Things balance out in the long run.

Comment: Really appreciate the reply @ficuscr.  I didn't even know max_input_vars existed.  Trying to edit it now to see if that was the issue - I suspect it is.

Comment: @ficuscr.  That did it - didn't realize I needed to restart php to take effect, but a search on SO helped.  That was the culprit.

Comment: @user2796515 Random drive-by downvotes are common. I gave it an upvote.